# How do I make this PHP login class create login sessions that don't expire?

Tags: php, cookies

Right now the login cookies expire every time the browser is closed. Is there a simple way to make them last a year instead?

Thanks!

http://pastebin.com/aB7Z1DNr

Comment: There is no any cookies usage in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set a longer lifetime on the session cookie.

Comment: Can you tell me where or point me in the right direction? Thanks!